# UnicodeDecodeError when opening a JPG with Tkinter and trying to watermark it using Pillow

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

When I run the code below, I get "

```
line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 644: character maps to <undefined>
```

I am stumped and very new to this.  Any help would be appreciated.  Code below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont


def open_and_watermark():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfile(filetypes=[('JPG Files', '*.jpg')])
    if filename:
        img = Image.open(filename)

        # Getting the height and width of the image
        width, height = img.size

        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
        text = "Generic Watermark"
        font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 45)

        textwidth, textheight = draw.textsize(text, font)

        x = width - textwidth - 10
        y = height - textheight - 15

        draw.text((x, y), text, font=font)

        # Saving the image
        img.save('watermarked.jpg')

        # Open the image
        img = Image.open('watermarked.jpg')
        img.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Image Watermarker")
    window.config(padx=100, pady=50, bg="white")

    title_label = Label(text="Image Watermarker", fg="black", bg="white", font=("Courier", 24))
    title_label.pack()

    canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=224, bg="white", highlightthickness=0)
    tomato_img = PhotoImage(file="tomato.png")
    canvas.create_image(100, 112, image=tomato_img)
    canvas.pack()

    # Add a Label widget
    label = Label(window, text="Click to select an image for watermarking", bg="white", font=("Courier", 14))
    label.pack()

    # Create a Button
    ttk.Button(window, text="Browse", command=open_and_watermark).pack()

    window.mainloop()
```

I tried opening a JPG file, but then when I attempt to add a watermark (which works when I directly pass it an image), I get this UnicodeDecodeError.  So the problem seems to be in

```
filename = filedialog.askopenfile(filetypes=[('JPG Files', '*.jpg')])
if filename:
    img = Image.open(filename)
```

Comment: Annnnnnnnd I posted too soon. If anyone else is stumped:img = Image.open(filename.name)

Comment: You can post it as an answer to your own question, to help others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is stumped:

```
img = Image.open(filename.name)
```